# Ошибка 403 Forbidden после добавления Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Пишу свой первый боевой проект на `Spring MVC`. Есть 3 класса пользователя: `Customer`, `Cook`, `Admin`. Все они наследуются от `User` класса по связям *@OneToOne*. Соответственно, есть 3 контроллера. После добавления `Spring Security` попытался протестить методы, например `GET`-метод у Админа, в консоли нет ни единой ошибки, а в `Swagger` `json` выдает следующую ошибку:

```java
{
  "timestamp": "2020-05-06T13:30:13.390+0000",
  "status": 403,
  "error": "Forbidden",
  "message": "Forbidden",
  "path": "/customer/change/password"
}
Response headers
 cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate 
 connection: keep-alive 
 content-type: application/json 
 date: Wed, 06 May 2020 13:30:13 GMT 
 expires: 0 
 keep-alive: timeout=60 
 pragma: no-cache 
 transfer-encoding: chunked 
 x-content-type-options: nosniff 
 x-frame-options: DENY 
 x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
```

Я пошел в `WebSecurityConfig` и убрал у `Customer` *hasRole*(подумал снять ограничение по роли и запустить его метод в Swagger, но тоже самое).

WebSecurityConfig:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.configs;

import com.tinychiefdelights.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // Поля
    //
    private UserService userService;


    // Injects in SETTERS
    //
    @Autowired
    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }



    // Methods
    //
    // Тут мы переопределяем метод конфигураций
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/cook/**").hasRole("COOK");
//                .antMatchers("/customer/**").hasRole("CUSTOMER");
//                .anyRequest().authenticated()
//                .and()
//                .exceptionHandling()
//                .and()
//                .formLogin()
//                .loginPage("/login")
//                .permitAll()
//                .and()
//                .logout()
//                .permitAll();
    }


    // Тут мы переопределяем для работы с внешней БД
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }


    // Тут мы используем encoder для шифрования паролей
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    // Возвращаем сервис пользовател для userDetServ
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return userService;
    }
}
```

Для примера приведу класс Customer:

Customer:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFound;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NotFoundAction;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", schema = "public")
public class Customer {

    public Customer() { // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }


    // Поля

    // name, lastName, login, password берем от класса User через связи;

    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "wallet")
    private double wallet;


    //Relationships
    //
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id") // Join without Customer in User class
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    private User user;

    //Лист заказов
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore // Таким образом я предотвратил рекурсию
    private List<Order> orderList;
}
```

CustomerService:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.service;

import com.tinychiefdelights.exceptions.NotFoundException;
import com.tinychiefdelights.model.*;
import com.tinychiefdelights.repository.*;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


@Service
public class CustomerService extends UserService {

    // Поля
    //
    // Injects in setters
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    private CookRepository cookRepository;

    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    private DishRepository dishRepository;

    private ReviewRepository reviewRepository;



    // SETTERS
    //
    // Injects into Setters
    @Autowired
    public void setReviewRepository(ReviewRepository reviewRepository) {
        this.reviewRepository = reviewRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setDishRepository(DishRepository dishRepository) {
        this.dishRepository = dishRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setCookRepository(CookRepository cookRepository) {
        this.cookRepository = cookRepository;
    }


    @Autowired
    public void setOrderRepository(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setCustomerRepository(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }



    // Методы
    //
    // Внести деньги на счет
    public void depositMoney(Long id, double money) {
        Customer customer = customerRepository.getByIdAndUserRole(id, Role.CUSTOMER);
        try {
            customer.setWallet(customer.getWallet() + money);
            customerRepository.save(customer);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            throw new NotFoundException(id);
        }

    }


    // Вывести деньги со счета
    public void withdrawMoney(Long id, double money) {
        Customer customer = customerRepository.getByIdAndUserRole(id, Role.CUSTOMER);
        if (money <= customer.getWallet()) { // Делаем проверку, чтобы сумма указанная заказчиком была меньше кошелька
            customer.setWallet(customer.getWallet() - money);
            customerRepository.save(customer);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Введенная Вами сумма превышает остаток на счете!");
        }
    }


    // Оставить Отзыв
    public void setReview(String text, int rate, Long id) {
        try {
            Review review = new Review();
            review.setReview(text);
            review.setRate(rate);
            review.setCook(cookRepository.getByIdAndUserRole(id, Role.COOK));
            reviewRepository.save(review);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }

    }


    // Сделать Заказ
    public void makeOrder(String address, String phoneNumber, Long customerId,
                          Long cookId, List<Long> dishListId, Date date) { // Сделать заказ ()

        try {
            Order order = new Order();
            order.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
            order.setAddress(address);
            order.setDateOrder(date);
            order.setOrderStatus(true);
            order.setCustomer(customerRepository.getByIdAndUserRole(customerId, Role.CUSTOMER));
            order.setCook(cookRepository.getByIdAndUserRole(cookId, Role.COOK));
            /**Сделать через карзину**/
//            for (Long a: dishListId) {
//                dishList.add(dishRepository.getById(a));
//            }
//            order.setDishes(dishList);
            orderRepository.save(order);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
        }
    }


    // Изменить карточку заказчика
    public Customer editCustomer(Long id, User user, double wallet) {
        Customer customer = customerRepository.getByIdAndUserRole(id, Role.CUSTOMER);
        try {

            customer.setUser(user);
            customer.setWallet(wallet);
            return customerRepository.save(customer);

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new NotFoundException(id);
        }
    }


    // Отменить заказ
    public void cancelOrder(Long id) {
        Order order = orderRepository.getById(id);
        order.setOrderStatus(false); // Добавим сообщение !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        orderRepository.save(order);
    }
}
```

CustomerController:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.controller;

import com.tinychiefdelights.model.*;
import com.tinychiefdelights.repository.CustomerRepository;
import com.tinychiefdelights.service.CustomerService;
import com.tinychiefdelights.service.UserService;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


@Api(value = "Работа с Заказчиком", tags = {"Заказчик"})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerController {

    //Constructor
    //
    // Injects через конструктор
    @Autowired
    public CustomerController(CustomerRepository customerRepository, CustomerService customerService, UserService userService) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
        this.customerService = customerService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }


    // Fields
    // Injects into constructor
    //
    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    private final CustomerService customerService;

    private final UserService userService;


    // GET MAPPING
    //


    // POST MAPPING
    //
    // Сделать заказ
    @PostMapping("/make/order")
    public void makeOrder(String address, String phoneNumber, Long customerId,
                          Long cookId, @RequestParam List<Long> dishList, Date date) {
        customerService.makeOrder(address, phoneNumber, customerId, cookId, dishList, date);
    }


    // Оставить отзыв
    @PostMapping("/set/review")
    public void setReview(String text, int rate, Long id) {
        customerService.setReview(text, rate, id);
    }

    // PUT MAPPING
    //
    // Заказчик может редактировать свою карточку (поиск по ID)
    @PutMapping("/edit/{id}")
    Customer editCustomer(@PathVariable Long id, User user, @RequestParam double wallet) {
        return customerService.editCustomer(id, user, wallet);
    }


    // Снять деньги со своего депозита (Заказчик)
    @PutMapping("/{id}/withdraw/{money}")
    void withdrawMoney(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam double money) {
        customerService.withdrawMoney(id, money);
    }


    // Изменить свой пароль
    @PutMapping("/change/password")
    void changePassword(@RequestParam String login, @RequestParam String newPass) {
        userService.changePassword(login, newPass);
    }


    // Внести деньги на счет (Заказчик)
    @PutMapping("/{id}/deposit/money")
    public void depositMoney(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam double money) {
        customerService.depositMoney(id, money);
    }


    // Отменить Заказ
    @PutMapping("/cancel/order/{id}")
    public void cancelOrder(@PathVariable Long id){
        customerService.cancelOrder(id);
    }


    // DELETE MAPPING
    //
}
```

Так же класс User, от которого через связи работает Customer:

User:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;

import io.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

@ApiModel
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pg_user", schema = "public")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    public User() { // Пустой конструктор для Hibernate

    }


    // Поля
    private @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Size(min = 5, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;


    // Методы
    //
    // GrantedAuthority
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role));
    }


    // userName == login (одно и тоже)
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return login;
    }


    // Во всех флагах стоит TRUE, так как не используются
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
    //
}
```

ENUM ROLE:

```java
package com.tinychiefdelights.model;


public enum Role {

    COOK, ADMIN, CUSTOMER


}
```

P.S. В проекте нет Front'а вообще. Все методы я пробую в ручную через `Swagger` и до этого у меня все отлично работало!
В чем может быть проблема?

Пробовал и без hasRole. Пробовал просто через @RolesAllowed, не помогает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сконфигурировать нужно Spring Security и добавить Swagger в исключения, чтобы он не отбивал его по 403 ошибкам.

Comment: как это можно сделать?

Comment: загуглить можно)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для того, чтобы пофиксить данную проблему, в `WebSecurityConfig` класс в метод `configure` в начало добавляем:

```java
http
.cors().disable()
.csrf().disable()
```